# Dockerized Django - running manage.py results in segmentation fault

Tags: python, django, docker

I am running Django in a docker on a raspberry pi 4b with 8gb ram. When docker runs my startup script that includes some commands with `python3 manage.py ...` Django crashes with a segmentation fault AFTER executing the command successfully.

The simplest way of recreating this behaviour is:

Log into docker shell:
`docker exec -it django_backend /bin/bash`
Go into venv and then run: `python3 manage.py`
This lists all the options for manage.py as expected and then immediately after results in a segfault.

Output:

> Type 'manage.py help ' for help on a specific subcommand.
> Available subcommands:
>
> [auth]
>
> changepassword
> createsuperuser
> ...
>
> Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Memory is definitely not the issue, less than 20% of the available memory is in use. I tried multiple resets of the whole system. I also tried this on two other machines with 8GB ram and there I don't get a segfault.

Any ideas what could be the reason for this or how I could test for possible reasons?

Comment: Are the other machines also Raspberry Pis?

Comment: No the other machines are a ubuntu 18 PC and a ubuntu 18 laptop. The pi is ubuntu 20.4 server

Comment: Then they have a competely different CPU architecture and can't run the same binaries.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand - do you think the problem is with Docker and Raspberry pi? Or Django and Raspberry pi? But running these doesn't seem to be a problem in general. I don't use code that I compiled on a different machine. I just git clone the repository and then in Docker pip install all the imports like Django.